# UWP C# Windows IoT Read Text Line to Process Word

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, streamreader, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to read a `text file` by and extract the words from individual line to process. 
I am not too sure how to use the `streamreader` to read and process the text.

```
private async void readFile()
    {
        StorageFolder externalDevices = KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> externalDrives = await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync();
        StorageFolder usbStorage = externalDrives[0];

        StorageFolder Folder = await usbStorage.CreateFolderAsync(FolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        await usbStorage.GetFolderAsync(FolderName);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> FileList = await Folder.GetFilesAsync();


        foreach (StorageFile file in FileList)
        {

            string Text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            //StreamReader Text = new StreamReader(file);
            //I am not sure how to implement StreamReader to read individual line of the text.
        }
    }
```

The file I am reading is show in the picture below. 
Please advise. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Side note: If this is file format you've invented consider using something more generic. For example JSON is very common choice for structured data with a lot of support to parse it in all languages.

Comment: Hi @Alexei Levenkov I dont really know much about JSON as I am quite a noob. Any advise?

Comment: @mylim You can try this code piece: `var file = await usbStorage.GetFileAsync("MyTestFile.txt");
            var lines = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("" + line.Split(';')[0]);
            }`